# Use laptop display screen with usb

Tags: laptop, usb, external-display

I have a separate HP laptop monitor. I wanted to know if possible how can I use it with another laptop. That means I want to connect a monitor to a laptop. Is there any usb converter for this, to convert the cable to usb?

I am not very familiar with the termnologies for these equipments. I will try to explain: I dissambled my laptop and removed the display from it. The display was connected to the motherboard with a connector which has several small pins in one line. I don't know what we call this type of connector.

Thank you

Comment: I have an HDMI port and a VGA port, but the connector cable in the monitor is different from these ports.

Comment: Actually I just got this screen from one of my laptops.

Answer (score 0):

"separate HP laptop monitor" - this would use LVDS internally, and probably need a LVDS -> VGA or some other common video output adaptor , I'd probably start with a [LVDS -> VGA converter board of some sort](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=laptop%20vga&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=YU7&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&sclient=psy-ab&q=LVDS%20to%20vga%20converter&oq=LVDS%20to%20vga%20converter&gs_l=serp.3..0l3j0i22i30.5533.7333.2.7693.10.4.0.6.6.0.66.231.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.TZmQtqO_hys&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk&fp=a939d7798e0e45d7&biw=1600&bih=821). This would also mean you need power for the monitor, as per the needs of the, you'd then need a USB-> VGA converter to use that with a VGA output.

It probably would cost less than a real monitor, but be a fair bit more complicated. Your LCD panel probably has 2-3 different connectors - a wide thin LVDS connector, often a less wide thin control connector next to it, and up to 2 2 wire connectors for the inverter/lighting if they are there. LVDS converter boards often come with everything you need other than the power supply so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the termnologies for these equipments. 
I will try to explain:
I dissambled my laptop and removed the display from it. The display was connected to the motherboard with a connector which has several small pins in one line. I don't know what we call this type of connector.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav, this may be useful information in the actual original question.